# Cannot find the LWRP in custom cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am building a cookbook that installs my node js files and then sets up initd scripts for them.  Unfortunately I cannot call the non-default LWRP in the cookbook.

Here is the error from the chef-client run:

```
 26>> blah_node_as_service 'setting up pricing service' do
 27:      directory '/var/blah/blah-pricing/'
 28:      script 'pricing-http-server-cluster.js'
 29:      resource_name 'blah-pricing' 
 30:  end
 31:  

Running handlers:
[2015-06-05T14:57:40-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-06-05T14:57:40-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-06-05T14:57:40-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.961443247 seconds
[2015-06-05T14:57:40-04:00] ERROR: No resource or method named `frt_node_as_service' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'
[2015-06-05T14:57:40-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Here are the key files in cookbook.

```
blah@blah:~/chef-repo/cookbooks/blah-deploy$ ls resources/
default.rb  blahNodeAsService.rb

blah@blah:~/chef-repo/cookbooks/blah-deploy$ cat resources/blahNodeAsService.rb 
actions :install

default_action :install if defined?(default_action)

attribute :script, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attribute :directory, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attribute :resource_name, :kind_of => String, :required => true

blah@blah:~/chef-repo/cookbooks/blah-deploy$ cat providers/blahNodeAsService.rb 
use_inline_resources

action :install do

    converge_by("Installing.") do
      resp = setUpService
      @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(resp)  
    end

end



def load_current_resource

  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::BlahNodeAsService.new(@new_resource.name)
  @current_resource.directory(@new_resource.directory)
  @current_resource.script(@new_resource.script)
  @current_resource.resource_name(@new_resource.resource_name)

end

def setUpService
end
```

The cookbook is already included by the cookbook for the service AND the default LWRP (default.rb) in that cookbook is working fine.  Its this second LWRP that cannot be found.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you reference the LWRP by using a combination of cookbook name and LWRP resource name:

```
<cookbook-name>_<resource-name>
```

In the case above:

```
blah_deploy_blah_node_as_service
```

SO it looks like i should name it better, but it is at least working.

Comment: You can inplement the Resource as HWRP and the Provider using LWRP. This allows you to circumvent the automatic cookbook-name-prefixing and still have the benefits of LWRP providers. Examples from the great book "Customizing Chef": https://github.com/jonlives/customizing_chef/blob/master/part3_examples/cookbooks/testcookbook/libraries/wizardry_resource.rb + https://github.com/jonlives/customizing_chef/blob/master/part3_examples/cookbooks/testcookbook/providers/hogwarts.rb

Comment: Thanks for confirming, it helped me get to the next issue as to why it wasn't working!